# How to map Unevaluated over a list

Tags: evaluation, hold

I have a list `{a1, a2, ...... , an}`, in which all `a`s have been initialized to a number. I want to get:

```
 {Unevaluated[a1], Unevaluated[a2], ...... , Unevaluated[an]}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this using `Map`, without getting a list of `Unevaluated[value of ai]`?

Answer (score 10):

```
unevaluatedF = Function[{x}, Unevaluated@x, {HoldFirst, Listable}];

{a1, a2, a3} = {1, 2, 3};
unevaluatedF@{a1, a2, a3}
```

> {Unevaluated[a1], Unevaluated[a2], Unevaluated[a3]}

Answer (score 7):

you can try also:

```
{a1, a2, a3} = {1, 2, 3};
Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@{a1, a2, a3}

(*{Unevaluated[a1], Unevaluated[a2], Unevaluated[a3]}*)
```

Comment: beat me by ten seconds.  +1

Answer (score 3):

First a link to a presentation everyone should read:

- [Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

Now some additional methods:

```
List @@ Unevaluated /@ Hold[a1, a2, a3]

Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated @ {a1, a2, a3}
```

More contrived:

```
Unevaluated @@@ Thread @ Hold[{a1, a2, a3}]

{Unevaluated /@ Hold[a1, a2, a3]} // ReleaseHold

Delete[{Unevaluated /@ Hold[a1, a2, a3]}, {1, 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're seeking?

```
Unevaluated /@ {a1, a2, a3, a4}
```

(*

{Unevaluated[a1], Unevaluated[a2], Unevaluated[a3], Unevaluated[a4]}

*)

Comment: Not really, `a1, a2, a3` are all initialized, so if `a1 = 10`, I will get `Unevaluated[10]`, which could not be used in `Set`