# Recognition Power Head for numeric value

Tags: evaluation, syntax, functional-style, hold

We know:

```
Map[Head, {a, a^2, a^3}]
(* {Symbol, Power, Power} *)
```

and `Map[Head, {2, 2^2, 2^3}]` all of them will be known as `Integers`.

But how can we get the result of

```
Map[Head, {2, 2^2, 2^3}]`
```

> ```
> {Integer, Power, Power}
> ```

I mean how *Mathematica* recognize a value is a power of two others?

Comment: `#[[1, 0]] & /@ {Hold[2], Hold[2^2], Hold[2^3]}` gives `Integer, Power, Power`

Comment: Just for the record, *after* `2^2` evaluates and becomes `4`, it is *not* a `Power`.

Comment: Alternatively `SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]; f[x_]:=Head@Unevaluated@x; Map[f, Unevaluated@{2, 2^2, 2^3}]`

Comment: Have a look at `PrimePowerQ[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use solutions from [How to map Unevaluated over a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84106/5478) to prepare your list to be mapped with `Head`. E.g.:

```
Map[Head, Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated @ {1, 2^2, 2^3}]
```

> ```
> {Integer, Power, Power}
> ```